# QGIS Python way to see if line is on top of another line

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I want to be able to tell if a line from one layer is on top of a line of another line of a different layer. For example I want to see black lines are on top of the other lines in the image. My code is as follows:

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayerRegistry
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

layers = iface.legendInterface().layers()

for layer in layers:
   name = layer.name()
   if "Black" in name:
      blacklayer=layer
   if "Color" in name:
      colorlayer=layer
blackFeatures=[feat for feat in blacklayer.getFeatures()]
colorFeatures=[feat for feat in colorlayer.getFeatures()]
for colorFeat in colorFeatures:
   for blackFeat in blackFeatures:
      if colorFeat.geometry().within(blackFeat.geometry()):
        print 'in'
    if blackFeat.geometry().within(colorFeat.geometry()):
        print 'in'
```

I am not sure if order of lines matters but I haven't gotten anything to work. I have tried within, intersects, overlap, contains, crosses, and touches but nothing seems to work. I have snapping on, so the black line is completely on the color line. Any idea on how to get this to work?

[image]

Comment: Do you get what you expect when you try print blackFeatures and print colorFeatures?

Comment: Yes, I get the correct number of outputs that have the form: <qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x000000002576E2F0>

Comment: Is there a way to rotate all lines along their midpoint? This is the work around I was thinking because then the lines would not be perfectly lined up on each other. Rotate them by a very small amount so that it is unnoticeable to the eye but the software can tell. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: You might look at the options within the "clean" functions in the SAGA (I think) toolbox (in QGIS). I believe there is a tool that will remove the overlapping lines and return them as a separate vector layer. I don't use QGIS scripting much, but I'm surprised a simple intersect doesn't work. Another method might be to first buffer the black lines slightly, then use within or intersects. Your rotation method should also work, but what happens if the rotated line intersects more than one other line? Is that a problem for you? (The buffer idea has the same issue if you make the buffer too big)